# How to write Arabic font (ttf) in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, arabic

I am new to ConTeXt.I want to use **majalla.ttf** located at `"C:\Context\tex\texmf\fonts\truetype\public"`. I would like to use it without any modification. I have looked at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Arabic_fonts,
but it seems very confusing. Btw, I am using:

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.04
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: C:/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2020.11.19 11:28
mtx-context     | main context file: C:/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2020.11.19 11:28
```

```
sakkalmajalla          sakkalmajalla   sakkalmajalla       c:/windows/fonts/majalla.ttf
sakkalmajallabold      sakkalmajalla   sakkalmajallabold   c:/windows/fonts/majallab.ttf
sakkalmajallanormal    sakkalmajalla   sakkalmajalla       c:/windows/fonts/majalla.ttf
sakkalmajallaregular   sakkalmajalla   sakkalmajalla       c:/windows/fonts/majalla.ttf
```

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupbodyfont[majalla]
\starttext
أهلاً وسهلاً
\stoptext
```

The log file is: https://gofile.io/d/fc5RbG

Comment: Try with `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=majalla` in the command prompt to see if your font is found by ConTeXt first. If not, use `mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force`. Depending of the actual name of your font, you may need to use another name.

Comment: I have edited the question. There is no output.

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (14:15 GMT -05:00)**: You can use the predefined Arabic feature (so you don't need to define it first):

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\definefontfamily[main][serif][sakkalmajalla][features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont[main]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\starttext
أهلاً وسهلاً
\stoptext
```

Hans already fixed ligatures and diacritics in LMTX, so using only `context <myfilename>.tex` should work. If you have bugs to report, consider joining the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context).

**OLD ANSWER:**

ConTeXt has already found your font with the name `sakkalmajalla` which you should use instead of `majalla`. If you don't want to use typescripts as in the Wiki, the following seems to work with ConTeXt MkIV (`context --luatex <myfilename>.tex`). In latest LMTX lam-alif ligatures don't seem to work, so I'm going to report it in case it's a bug, so we'll need a bit of patience until it's fixed.

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
   init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
   liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,clig=yes,
   mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]
\definefontfamily[main][serif][sakkalmajalla][features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont[main]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\starttext
أهلاً وسهلاً
\stoptext
```

Comment: This only works for me if I add `\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one` as specified in the [Right-to-left Context Wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/RTL#Basics).